# You Tube api only allowing 50 uploads

Tags: c#, api, youtube

I seem to be only be able to upload 50 videos/hour using the you tube api. We produce videos for Real Estate clients and have for the past year or more been able to upload videos on demand but as of yesterday it seems to have been throttled back.

Is anybody else having this issue?

The Errror message I am getting is "An error prevented the upload from completing:
Response status code does not indicate success: 403 (Forbidden)"

Code snippet of how I am uploading the video as below

var video = new Google.Apis.YouTube.v3.Data.Video();

```
            video.Snippet = new VideoSnippet();
            video.Snippet.Title = ytVideo.YOU_TUBE_VIDEO_TITLE;
            video.Snippet.Description = ytVideo.YOU_TUBE_VIDEO_DESCRIPTION.Replace(">", "").Replace("<", "");
            video.Snippet.Tags = ytVideo.YOU_TUBE_VIDEO_TAGS.Split(new string[] { "," }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            video.Snippet.CategoryId = "22";

            video.Status = new VideoStatus();
            video.Status.PrivacyStatus = "public";
            video.Status.Embeddable = true;

            using (var fileStream = new FileStream(mp4, FileMode.Open))
            {
                const int KB = 0x400;
                var minimumChunkSize = 256 * KB;

                var videoInsertRequest = myService.Videos.Insert(video, "snippet,status", fileStream, "video/mp4");

                videoInsertRequest.ProgressChanged += videoInsertRequest_ProgressChanged;
                videoInsertRequest.ResponseReceived += videoInsertRequest_ResponseReceived;
                videoInsertRequest.ChunkSize = minimumChunkSize;
                videoInsertRequest.UploadAsync().Wait();
            }
```

Comment: Youtube has [documentation of quota limit calculation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started#quota). What is your quota limit and what is your usage pattern?

Comment: We are well within our quotas, nothing has been changed at our end.

Comment: Youtube also has [documentation of error codes](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/errors#videos_youtube.videos.insert) for the videos insert request.  The errorMessage of the response might have more information to help answer your question.

Comment: unfortunately did't help the Google.Apis.Upload.IUploadProgress object only returns Status: Failed Error.Message: Response status code does not indicate success: 403 (Forbidden)

Comment: I am getting this too - you seem to be able to upload 50 videos, then get throttled to 1 every 15 minutes. I'm still to work out when this throttle gets reset.